# How to finish activity from other intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Example : Activity A to B to C to main menu, How to finish Activity A in main menu when user pressed exit button  ?

Comment: What is the "exit button"? I think a flowchart would be easier to read than what you're trying to say. I have no clear idea what you're asking/

Comment: You should use the `android-activity` tag instead of `activity` here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i mean, when user exit application and start again, application back again to Activity A.

Comment: Let me know if I understand correctly. Do you want the application to "forget" that it was in activity C and always open A when they start your app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can finish activity A from activity B, with code like this in the activity A to start activity B:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(A.this, B.class), 1);
```

Create onActivityResult method in activity A like this:

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == 2)
{
    finish();
}}
```

On activity B you must implement setResult like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(2);
        }
```

Activity A will finished when you call setResult on activity B.

Comment: **OK AryaSusastra**, _if you have a problem again, please ask here._

Answer (score 0):

From the main home screen, you shouldn't implement a button that finishes an activity and exits the application... this is what the back button is for.

Comment: I have Quiz application with two Activity. Activity A is question 1 and Activity B question 2. Activity c is value. When check the value then exit from application and start application again, application start in Activity A, not in main menu. From activity A to B not finished so when from Activity B back to Activity A the answer in order not to lose. How the sollution?

Comment: This is what I understand. You have a quiz application with two activity. You want to remember the value the user had clicked in Activity A and Activity B. Use those in Activity C to show results?

If that's the case use a database or write to a file or if the questions are low, use Shared Preference. :)